# Operator overloading "+" & "=" issue -- school asst

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading, operator-keyword, copy-assignment

first time poster here but lurker for a couple of months now. Currently indulging in C++ with a small amount of Java knowledge as well from prior Comp Sci courses at school. I apologize if some of you look at this and are disappointed since there are already questions about operator overloads, but I could not put together what exactly is wrong with my program going off of what I was able to find on here.

This question in particular has to do with the + & = operators. I've done a couple of programs already in class that involved both of these overloads, and I didn't seem to have any difficulty making the program function properly; however, there must be some distinct differences from these prior programs and my current one that I'm failing to see that goes beyond my understanding of how each operator overload works.

The error messages themselves make the issue seem almost too easy to fix as it's just an operand matching issue apparently, but I still have been unable to find the correct syntax to correct these errors. They are as follows:

```
"1>...\grademain.cpp(19): error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand 1>operand of type 'const char [12]' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>...\grade.h(39): could be 'Grade &Grade::operator =(const Grade &)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(Grade, const char [12])'  "
```

and

```
"1>...\grademain.cpp(26): error C2679: binary '+' : no operator found which takes a right-hand 1>operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>...\grade.h(40): could be 'Grade Grade::operator +(const Grade &)'
1>\grade.h(16): or       'int operator +(const Grade &)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(Grade, int)'  "
```

The code is as follows:

GradeMain.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Grade.h"

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    Grade student1("Tom Smith", 90);        //declare initialized object
    cout << "First: " << student1 << endl;

    Grade student2;
    student2 = "Bill Miller";   //uses conversion constructor           //  ERROR # 1
    cout << "Second: " << student2 << endl;

    Grade student3;
    student3 = student1;
    cout << "Third: " << student3 << endl;

    int adjusted_grade = student1 + 4;                                  //  ERROR # 2
    cout << "adjusted grade of first by 4 points gives " << adjusted_grade << endl;

    //test equality operator
    if (student1 == student2)
        cout << "\nerror - students should not be equal\n";
    else
        cout << "\nstudent 1 is not equal to student 2\n";

    if (student1 == student3)
        cout << "\nstudent 1 is equal to student 3\n";
    else
        cout << "\nerror - student 1 should be equal to student 3\n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Grade.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Grade.h"


//  Copy Assignment
Grade &Grade::operator=(const Grade &temp)
{
    name = temp.name;
    grade = temp.grade;

    return *this;
}

//  Addition Operator Overload
Grade Grade::operator+(const Grade &temp)
{
    Grade temp1;

    temp1.grade = grade + temp.grade;       

    return *this;
}

//  Output Operator Overload
ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Grade &p)
{
    os << p.name << " " << p.grade;

    return os;
}

//  Input Operator Overload
istream& operator>>(istream &in, const Grade &p)
{
    //  No purpose for program -- User does not input anything
    return in;
}

//  Comparison Operator Overload
bool Grade::operator==(const Grade &temp)
{
    if(grade == temp.grade)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Grade.h:

```
using namespace std;

class Grade
{
    //  Friend Function Prototypes
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& , const Grade&);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& , const Grade&);        //  Not necessary -- deleting  
    friend bool operator==(const Grade&, const Grade&);     
    friend int operator+(const Grade&);
private:
    string name;
    int grade;
public:
    //  Default Constructor
    Grade();

    //  Constructor
    Grade(string studentName, int studentGrade)
    {
        name = studentName;
        grade = studentGrade;
    }

    //  Copy Constructor
    Grade(const Grade &obj)
    {
        name = obj.name;
        grade = obj.grade;
    }

    //  Operator Overloads
    Grade& operator=(const Grade &);        //  Copy Assignment
    Grade operator+(const Grade &);
    Grade& operator<<(const Grade &);
    Grade& operator>>(const Grade &);
    bool operator==(const Grade &); 
};
```

Part of my confusion with the operator= issue is that when I assigned student3 to student1, there was no problem, yet when I simply assign student2 = "Bill Miller", it experiences an operand issue. I had thought this would just create the object of student2("Bill Miller", 0) essentially, but I must be wrong somewhere. I can only imagine that whatever rectifies this would then also rectify the operand issue with updating student1's grade when assigning a new variable based off its current assigned grade. Something tells me it could possibly just be how the function is structured at the moment, where perhaps the operator+ overload would need to be something similar to "int Grade::operator+(const Grade &)" rather than "Grade Grade:operator+(const Grade &)", but all of my efforts to find the proper syntax so far have been futile.

Any direction you could point me in to better understand how to get out of the situation I am in would be absolutely excellent, just don't give me the answer straight out(of course)!! Seeing as this is an assignment for class, any suggestions should only pertain to Grade.cpp and Grade.h due to GradeMain being supplied by the instructor.

Many thanks for reading :)

Comment: An `operator+` that takes a `Grade` on the left and an `int` on the right, returning an `int`, would look like `int Grade::operator+(int) const`, but it might be better to just implement a getter.

Comment: `Grade::operator+` should return `temp1`, not `*this`. Also `temp1` should be initialized from `*this` so that it picks up the name

Comment: This is not bad as homework questions go, but you might want to explain more of your reasoning.  For example, why would you expect the zero to automatically be given as the second parameter to `Grade(string,int)` constructor?

Comment: For that particular example, I remember reading another posted question on here where someone had a similar error, and I remember someone responding with something along the lines of the compiler automatically assuming the value is 0 if none is input to accommodate the constructor. I'm sorry if I'm being vague on my explanation :(

Answer (score 2):

When you say

```
student2 = "Bill Miller";
```

this would involve two user-defined conversions: one from a `const char *` to a `std::string`, and the other from a `std::string` to a `Grade`.  However, C++ only allows one automatic user-defined conversion to take place.

Moreover, you have a constructor that takes a `std::string`, but it also takes an extra parameter, so it can't be used automatically to convert a `std::string` to a `Grade`.  Only constructors that can be called with a single argument can be used for conversion.

For the other error

```
int adjusted_grade = student1 + 4;
```

there is no `operator+` that takes a `Grade` and an `int`, and there is no way to convert the `4` to a `Grade` and no way to convert a `Grade` to another type that could be used with adding an `int`.

Comment: The second user-defined conversion isn't even there.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm not too savvy with C++ and all of its intricacies yet, so I did not even know about the rule on user-defined conversions(that or it had slipped my mind). So then it would appear that I may need to change the string to a char array of 12 for the "Bill Miller" portion, to limit user-defined conversions...if I'm understanding correctly. As for the second part, that line you quoted is what the teacher expects to be tested, so I may have to run it by them to see what they expect if performing that is impossible given conversion issues.

Comment: @Gooeybanana Instead of writing a converting constructor, consider providing an `operator=` overload that takes a `std::string` argument.

Comment: So I changed it to "string Grade::operator=(string temp)" and set name = temp, then returned name.(loledits -- did not know proper formatting xD) This ended up fixing the first error, but upon building, I received 
"1>GradeMain.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Grade::Grade(void)" (??0Grade@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main"
as an error when I commented the addition and comparison part out to see if it would output correctly =/

Comment: @Gooeybanana No, don't replace your copy assignment operator. This would be a separate overload. And your linker error is because you didn't actually define Grade's default constructor.

Comment: Oh! I was not aware you could overload twice like that...many apologies, I guess I have just not seen enough operator overload examples to really know as of yet, but this fixed the problem! The conditional statement also checked out, so now all I have left is this int issue.

Comment: Aha! I changed the member function to "int Grade::operator+(int temp)" and added temp with grade into a temp1 variable, and that ended up correcting the second error :D And also, in regards to the default constructor being defined, that makes sense now. I remember always having to do that with my Java programs, but for some reason not defining anything in another program worked out fine so I assumed it would again here. Many thanks for clearing this all up!!! Now to tidy this program up ^_^